# Письма отправленные через mail() по-разному отображаются на разных почтовых сервисах

Tags: email, objective-c, php, afnetworking, кодировка

при выполнении POST-запроса к php скрипту средствами AFNetworking 2.0.2, содержащим в одном из параметров кириллицу, возникает конфликт кодировок.

часть кода отсылающая запрос:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"text": @"как нам пришлось помучаться"};
[manager POST:@"http://url-to-phpfile" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

php-скрипт принимающий запрос (файл в utf-8):

```
<?php
    $title = 'новое письмо'; 
    $mess =  $_POST["text"];  
    $to = 'мой_емейл';  
    $from='mail@test.ru';  
    mail($to, $title, $mess, 'From:'.$from);   
?>
```

после отправки запроса на мой ящик падает письмо с правильно отображающимся заголовком и корявым телом письма:

> я┌п╣я│я┌п╬п╡п╟я▐ я│я┌я─п╬п╨п╟

декодер от студии лебедева подсказал что это нужный текст, только в кодировке KOI8-R. В какой момент происходит перекодировка текста?

**UPDATE**
проблема с кодировками решилась при переходе с mail.ru на gmail.com. почему возникает конфликт кодировок с разными почтовыми сервисами?

Comment: Вообще он работает в UTF-8, судя по тому что у Вас получается KOI то могу подумать что это дело рук самой программы mail. пробывали ли Вы запрос послать обычным curl ом или подобному инструменту?

Comment: И что у Вас храниться в переменной  $mess до отправки пиьсма?

Comment: Запрос через hurl.it тоже получился в koi. В переменной mess ничего не хранится, выше представлен весь код срипта отправки письма.

Comment: Если онлайн сервис тоже передает в koi, значить проблема на стороне сервера. Где еще могут задаваться параметры кодировки?

Comment: Проблема решилась сменой почтового адреса получателя! Раньше отправлял на mail.ru, где и получал кракозябры, а gmail.com все показывает как хочется. в чем причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина некорректного определения кодировки сервисом mail.ru не ясна, для корректного отображения необходимо в параметре `$headers` функции mail явно указать кодировку (в моем случае UTF-8

```
$header = "From: \"Admin\" <admin@site.com>\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"";
mail($to, $title, $mess, $header);
```